# How do I insert a serialized Java object into Cassandra using the Hector API?

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, hector

I need to write a Java object to Cassandra using its Hector API. I have a Set object which I have tried to serialize and then use it in Hector's insert() on a mutator for the column family. I keep getting errors that the object is not serializable. I could not find any documentation for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a Java object to a Cassandra Column in the following way:

```
StringSerializer stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();
ObjectSerializer flatten=ObjectSerializer.get();
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator (keySpace, stringSerializer);
HColumn<String, Object> column=HFactory.createColumn ("1", object1, stringSerializer,flatten);   
mutator.insert ("pages",COLUMN_FAMILY, column);
```

Here, object1 is the object that I want to write to Cassandra. keySpace is of type me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace, "1" is the column name, "pages" is the row key and COLUMN_FAMILY is a String stating the name of the Column Family.
I was making a mistake in serializing the object first and then writing into insert() while that is not required.

Comment: what is the COLUMN_FAMILY structure that you have used for this specific case? thx

Comment: COLUMN_FAMILY is a string containing the name of the column family.

Comment: thanks, I understand that, but what i meant is about specifically the structure what you have used in your example! because I'm having problems depending on it!!

Comment: I had only one column named "1" with a string row key. I was storing objects under that column.